# Join 2 tables with where and MAX

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, sql-server-2005, max

I have 2 tables;

TableSN

```
snID SerialNR Unit Version
 1    123     A      A1
 2    456     A      A2
```

TableDelivery

```
dID SerialNR Team
 1    456      US
 2    456      GE
 3    456      FI
```

Result

```
snID   SerialNR   Unit   Version  Team
 1       123       A       A1
 2       456       A       A2      FI
```

I need to get table based on `TableSN and SerialNR`, listing where Version is given. In the same table I need to show latest entered `data (= MAX(dID))` for Team-column. I am able to get table to show correctly when there is Team-data available.

My query is like this

```
SELECT TableSN.snID, TableSN.SerialNR, TableSN.Unit, TableSN.Version, TableDelivery.Team
FROM TableSN 
     LEFT OUTER JOIN TableDelivery ON TableDelivery. SerialNR = TableSN. SerialNR 
     LEFT OUTER JOIN ( 
         SELECT SerialNR, MAX(dID) AS snRank
         FROM TableDelivery AS TableDelivery _1
         GROUP BY SerialNR
     ) AS NewTeam ON TableDelivery. SerialNR = NewTeam. SerialNR AND TableDelivery.dID = NewTeam.snRank
WHERE (TableSN.Version = @Version)
```

How do I get `SerialNR` visible where there are no Team available?

Thank you for guidance and support.

This is what is needed:

[[image: enter image description here]]

Comment: can you please mention tables with some records.

Comment: TableSN.SerialNR should always be visible as long as TableSN.Version = @Version is true - since TableSN is your first table and the others are LEFT joined to it  -as far as I can see

Comment: Actually with "LEFT" join it takes ALL TableDelivery data visible. With "RIGHT" join it will show correctly, but it leaves out if there is no data for SerialNR in TableDelivery. "RIGHT" join is the one I need, but I need to have also the ones that has no Team info in TableDelivery.

Comment: Given my answer below, please check once @makelei

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this :**

```
SELECT TableSN.snID, TableSN.SerialNR, TableSN.Unit, TableSN.Version, TableDelivery.Team
FROM TableSN 
LEFT JOIN TableDelivery ON TableDelivery.SerialNR = TableSN. SerialNR AND 
                           TableDelivery.dID = (SELECT MAX(dID) 
                                                FROM TableDelivery AS t         
                                                WHERE t.SerialNR = TableSN. SerialNR)
WHERE (TableSN.Version = @Version)
```

Comment: Thank You! This was what I was looking for. Works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

```
  DECLARE @Version VARCHAR(5)
SET @Version = 'A1'

     SELECT Ts.snID,ts.SerialNR,ts.Unit,ts.Version,TD.Team FROM @TableSN ts left join @TableDelivery td ON ts.SerialNR = td.SerialNR
     WHERE ts.Version = @Version

     UNION 

     SELECT Ts.snID,ts.SerialNR,ts.Unit,ts.Version,TD.Team FROM @TableDelivery TD left join @TableSN TS ON TD.SerialNR = ts.SerialNR
     WHERE dID = (SELECT MAX(dID) FROM @TableDelivery) 

    **output**

    snID    SerialNR    Unit    Version Team
    1        123         A        A1    NULL
    2        456         A        A2    FI
```

Comment: Thanks. I am using MSSQL and with this code, it gives: "The Declare SQL construct or statement is not supported."

Comment: Above code is related to MSSQL only, try to execute one more time, May I know which version of SQL Server you are using?

Comment: I edited my answer, please check, you are getting that error as you are using SQL Version 2005

Answer (score 0):

You need to include null condition in your sql as show below:

```
SELECT TableSN.snID, TableSN.SerialNR, TableSN.Unit, TableSN.Version, TableDelivery.Team
FROM TableSN 
LEFT OUTER JOIN TableDelivery ON TableDelivery. SerialNR = TableSN. SerialNR 
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT SerialNR, MAX(dID) AS snRank
                    FROM TableDelivery AS TableDelivery _1
                    GROUP BY SerialNR) AS NewTeam ON (TableDelivery. SerialNR = NewTeam. SerialNR 
                    OR (TableDelivery. SerialNR IS NULL AND NewTeam. SerialNR IS NULL))
                    AND TableDelivery.dID = NewTeam.snRank
WHERE (TableSN.Version = @Version)
```

Comment: This is resulting that ALL deliveries for Serial number will be listed. I need each Serial number ONLY once and last delivery information. Am I missing something?